# How can I integrate the Google Actions responses in a webhook response in Dialogflow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am trying to figure out how I can embed Google Actions responses, such as the [cards carousel](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#carousel_selector), in a webhook response for DialogFlow.

On https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/webhook, I found the following information:

*The response format of the Dialogflow webhook contains the standard Dialogflow webhook response contents and a **data.google object** that closely resembles a standard conversation webhook response with the following general differences.*

So I tried extending the webhook response with a `data.google` structure as following:

```
{
   "fulfillmentText":"Please select any card you like.",
   "data":{
      "google":{
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

When testing in the [console](https://console.actions.google.com), I get the following error:

*Webhook call failed. Error: Failed to parse webhook JSON response: Cannot find field: data in message google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse.*

Looking to the [definition of `WebhookResponse`](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2beta1.WebhookResponse), it looks like there is indeed no `data` field.

I am going around in circles. My question is basically: how can I enrich Dialogflow webhook responses with Google Actions responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Actions on Google still refers to the Dialogflow V1 protocol documentation and the node.js library from Google only supports the V1 protocol. Since it sounds like you're trying to use Dialogflow V2 Beta, you need to change how you've formatted the JSON.

Instead of using the `data.google` data structure, as in V1, V2Beta uses the `payload.google` field (that is, a `payload` object that has a `google` object in it). (See https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#requirements under the "Response" section and click on the V2 tab.)

The `payload.google` field would be set to the same thing the contents of the `data.google` field was set to.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize the documentations were still V1 oriented. I will start with experimenting to embed Google Actions into the `payload` field.

Comment: Note for future readers: This comment is not up-to-date and thus not completely correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49131136/9038652 for working examples.

Comment: Actually, thank you for reminding me that I wanted to fix this. I've now corrected the answer.