# Retrieve Google Smart Home events in Dialogflow fulfillment service

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-smart-home

I am trying to forward Google Smart Home events to my Dialogflow fulfillment service. I am creating 3 intents with no input or output contexts set, no training phases and with the following events:

- `action_devices_SYNC`
- `action_devices_EXECUTE`
- `action_devices_QUERY`

See also https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvkGj.jpg.

Is that correct? I can't find confirmation in the docs, so that's why I am asking it here.

**reasoning**

The reason why I asked about connecting Google Smart Home with my Dialogflow endpoint is that I already have that endpoint in place. I hoped I could do something similar as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119822/9038652, where I bound a Dialogflow intent to the `actions_intent_OPTION` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a reason to use Dialogflow to do smart home fulfillment, and it's actually not possible.

Dialogflow is great for taking unstructured user utterances and making sense of them. However, with [smart home](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/), Google handles all of the NLU and parsing. You, as the integration, will just receive a JSON request and will be expected to provide a JSON response.

So you will skip using Dialogflow and instead just build your webhook to parse the intents and give a valid response.

Dialogflow's service does not have a way to take in an intent name and expose a single endpoint URL that can be called by the Google Assistant. It also does not have integration with an OAuth server to do the account linking step.

Comment: Nick, thank you for your feedback. The reason why I asked about connecting Google Smart Home with my Dialogflow endpoint is that I already have that endpoint in place. I hoped I could do something similar as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119822/9038652, where I bound a Dialogflow intent to the `actions_intent_OPTION` event. So I guess these kind of flows are not possible for Google Smart Home events, while they are for plain Assistant events (such as the carousel selector)?

Comment: That said, I perfectly understand why Dialogflow is not intended for this integration (there is no custom intent matching required, as you explained), but it would make sense (in my case) from a practical point of view. It's just a quick way to get started.

Comment: Those flows were designed in a way that can be handled through Dialogflow, whereas this was not meant for smart home integrations. If you do have a webhook already developed, you can create a new webhook endpoint to handle smart home events and connect to whatever cloud infrastructure you have, but you cannot do it with dialogflow as a direct intermediary.